# Keep getting several exceptions in method - android studio

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview, indexoutofboundsexception, findviewbyid

I keep getting several exceptions in the following method (which is part of a fragment) and i just can't find a solution.

The intention of that code is that i receive a String via bluetooth from which i want to "extract" specific data (temperature measurements), convert those received bytes into an int and display it on a TextView element in the UI.

```
public void showCurrentTemperature(int id){

    byte[] receivedTempArray = new byte [18];
    receivedTempArray = MainActivity.received.getBytes();
    byte[] TempData = new byte [6];

    if (receivedTempArray[0] == 83 & receivedTempArray[1] == 84 & 
        receivedTempArray[2] == 71 & receivedTempArray[3] == 105 &
        receivedTempArray[6] == 116){

        TempData[0] = receivedTempArray[8];
        TempData[1] = receivedTempArray[9];
        TempData[2] = receivedTempArray[11];
        TempData[3] = receivedTempArray[12];

        String TempValueHex = new String(TempData);

        int TempInt = Integer.parseInt(TempValueHex, 16);
        TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(id);

        view.setText(TempInt + "");
    }
}
```

first one is a nullpointerexception here:

```
receivedTempArray = MainActivity.received.getBytes();
```

second one is an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=6; index=6.

This exception is thrown after opening the whole fragment but the only arrays are in this method.

the third exception is another nullpointerexception in this line:
    TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(id);

i guess it's the "findViewByID" causing. But i've declared the method in the onViewCreated. So why am I keep getting a nullpointerexception?

```
@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    showCurrentTemperature(R.id.TemperatureTextView);
}
```

Edit:
The "received" string from the mainActivity is created in here:

```
public static String received;
void receivedData(String data) {
    //Log.d(TAG, getString(R.string.connection_RX_data) + data);
    received = data;
    Fragment f = this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
    if (f == mRgbwFragment) {
        mRgbwFragment.receivedData(data);
    }
    if (f == mServiceFragment) {
        mServiceFragment.receivedData(data);
    }
}
```

and the data-string is created in here:

```
private void listenForData() {
    final Handler rxMessageHandler = new Handler();
    // Handler needed to access outer class from inner Thread
    mStopListenForData = false;             // stop inner Thread flag
    mDataInBuffer = new byte[256];          // temporary buffer
    mDataInBufferPosition = 0;              // position of last byte in the buffer
    Thread dataInThread = new Thread(       // Thread listens for incoming data
            new Runnable() {                // Uses inner classes
                public void run() {
                    while (!Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() && !mStopListenForData) {
                        try {
                            int bytesAvailable = mInStream.available();
                            if (bytesAvailable > 0) {
                                byte[] packetBytes = new byte[bytesAvailable];
                                bytesAvailable = mInStream.read(packetBytes);
                                Log.d(TAG, bytesAvailable + "are available Bytes");
                                   final String data = new String(packetBytes); //create a sting from the received byte array
                                rxMessageHandler.post(
                                        new Runnable() {    // Process received String
                                            public void run() {
                                                Log.d(TAG, mActivity.getString(R.string.connection_RX_data) + data);
                                                mActivity.receivedData(data);
                                            }
                                        }
                                );
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, mActivity.getString(R.string.connection_error) + " listenForData runnable");
                            mStopListenForData = true;
                        }
                        synchronized (this) {
                            try {           // Wait a while before listening again
                                wait(mActivity.getResources().getInteger(R.integer.connection_wait_TXRX));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                Log.e(TAG, mActivity.getString(R.string.connection_error) + " while waiting");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
    );
    dataInThread.start();
}
```

Comment: Can you post more code showing where `MainActivity.received` is getting set.  Your first two issues may be caused by trying to access this value too soon.

Comment: You'll find it now above

Answer (score 0):

**(For your final issue)** My guess is getView() is your problem.  onViewCreated is called after creation of your view hierarchy but before it has been attached to the parent.

> **onViewCreated** - Called immediately after onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle) has returned, but before any saved state has been restored in to the view. This gives subclasses a chance to initialize themselves once they know their view hierarchy has been completely created. The fragment's view hierarchy is not however attached to its parent at this point.

I'm assuming getView() is a function you created - however if it resembles:

```
getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
```

Then you are trying to access your TextView through the parent.  However your view hierarchy has not been attached to its parent when onViewCreated is called.

*The solution?* Use a reference to your view that does not involve the parent for findViewByID (perhaps create a class variable from the return value of your inflater in onCreateView)

Comment: Thank's, that was helpful!